# Saving repeater items into SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a repeater binding it using a sql data-source and I'm trying to insert the user selections -some labels values- into a database.

I'm trying to figure out why the code is inserting only one record to the database while it should insert all repeater values.

Thanks to help as much as you can.

*Code behind*:

```
Public Sub InsertFuncation()

    ' Define data objects
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlstring As String

    ' Read the connection string 
    myConn = New SqlConnection("xxx")

    ' Create command
    sqlstring = "INSERT INTO tbl_QZ_AgentResults (Username, ExamID, QuestionID, Question_CorrectAnswer, Question_UserSelection, Question_Score, TRN_AddedOn) VALUES (@Agnt_LdnUsername, @ExamID, @QuestionID, @Question_CorrectAnswer, @Question_UserSelection, @Question_Score, @TRN_AddedOn)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
    For Each rpItem As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        Dim QID As Label = TryCast(rpItem.FindControl("QuestionIDLabel"), Label)
        Dim QCorrectAnswer As Label = TryCast(rpItem.FindControl("lbl_CORRECTANS"), Label)
        Dim QUserAnswer As Label = TryCast(rpItem.FindControl("lbl_USERANS"), Label)
        Dim QScore As Label = TryCast(rpItem.FindControl("lbl_QSCORE"), Label)

        'Perform your insert operation.

        ' Add command parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cmd.Parameters("@Username").Value = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 11)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExamID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters("@ExamID").Value = Request.QueryString("ExamID").ToString

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TRN_AddedOn", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime)
        cmd.Parameters("@TRN_AddedOn").Value = DateTime.Now

        If QID IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@QuestionID").Value = QID.Text
        End If

        If QCorrectAnswer IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Question_CorrectAnswer", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@Question_CorrectAnswer").Value = QCorrectAnswer.Text
        End If

        If QUserAnswer IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Question_UserSelection", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@Question_UserSelection").Value = QUserAnswer.Text
        End If

        If QScore IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Question_Score", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@Question_Score").Value = QScore.Text
        End If

        ' Enclose database code in Try-Catch-Finally
        Try
            ' Open the connection
            myConn.Open()
            ' Execute the command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' Display success message
            MsgBox("Entered Successfully !", Me.Page, Me)
            'ClearInputs(Page.Controls)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Display error message
            MsgBox("Error !", Me.Page, Me)
        Finally
            ' Close the connection
            myConn.Close()
            Response.Redirect("GetResult.aspx?ExamID=" & Request.QueryString("ExamID"))
        End Try
        ' End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*.aspx code*

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">            
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="QuestionID:" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="QuestionIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' Visible="false"/>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="ExamID:" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="ExamIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExamID") %>' Visible="false"/>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Q:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="QuestionTextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>' />
                <br />

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_SELECTANSWER" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Q_Answer_1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_Answer_1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_Answer_2") %>' />
                    <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_Answer_3") %>' />
                    <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_Answer_4") %>' />
                    <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CORRECTANS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_Correct_Ans") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_USERANS" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_QSCORE" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>       
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FBB-DSL-DBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT TOP (5) QuestionID, QuestionText, ExamID, Q_Answer_1, Q_Answer_2, Q_Answer_3, Q_Answer_4, Q_Correct_Ans FROM tbl_QZ_Question WHERE (ExamID = @ExamID) ORDER BY NEWID()">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="ExamID" 
                    QueryStringField="ExamID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />

     <asp:Button ID="btn_SAVEANSWERS" runat="server" Text="Save Answers !" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Move the response redirect from try catch clause to be after the for each

```
        Response.Redirect("GetResult.aspx?ExamID=" & Request.QueryString("ExamID"))
```